# initial state is true for a brief moment or something that causes tailwind classname to trigger

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

So here is a sidebar wrapper div that makes it appear and disappear

```
<div
  className={`fixed w-full max-w-full lg:max-w-[507px] 2xl:max-w-[35.208vw] right-0 top-0 bottom-0 z-[99] bg-primary overflow-hidden transition-transform duration-700 ${isSidebarOpen === true ? "transform-none" : "translate-x-full"}`}
>
```

When I refresh my browser, for a brief moment, the sidebar appears initially and then it slides to hides itself. How to make it initially hidden?

The weird thing is, It works on some of my coworker's pc, some of them has this bug.

I got the state from globalContext because other components have to use it

```
const { closeSidebar, isSidebarOpen } = useGlobalContext()
```

and the state's initial value is false.

```
const [isSidebarOpen, setSidebarOpen] = useState<boolean>(false)
```